# Unix utility which executes a command and tests its exit status

Tags: shell, unix, ocaml, automated-tests

I am writing automated tests for the [Gasoline](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline), an OCaml library implementing application templates.  Applications are expected to fail with a prescribed exit code in certain circumstances, like exit code 64 `EXIT_USAGE` when the application is called with an ill-formed command line:

```
% ./punishment.byte -x
punishment.byte: illegal option -- x
Usage: punishment.byte [-n number] [-p paragraph] [-c configfile]
Exit 64
```

Is there a standard Unix utility that can be used to run the subcommand `./punishment.byte -x` and exit with status code 0 if the subcommand exited with status code 64? Something like

```
% expect_status 64 ./punishment.byte -x
punishment.byte: illegal option -- x
Usage: punishment.byte [-n number] [-p paragraph] [-c configfile]
Exit 0
```

As I am using a Makefile to orchestrate the tests, a legible statement such as `expect_status 64 ./punishment.byte -x` would be nice to have.

**Notes**

1. The `Exit` line in console interaction examples is informative and not part of the output.
2. I am well aware that I can write such a tool and how to do it, I just want to be sure there is no standard command doing that already.

Comment: I don't know a standard utility (there might be one) but the shell stores the last exit code in the $? variable. I would think you could write your own utility in a few lines of shell script, e.g. if [ "$?" -eq "$expected" ] then exit 0 fi.

Comment: Yes, there's a standard utility; it's called the shell. 8-)}

Comment: You might be interested in [GNU Autotest](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Using-Autotest.html).

Comment: Which shell are you using?  If csh or tcsh, then you need `$status` rather than `$?`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, ah! ☺  I am well aware that I can test the exit status of a command in the shell, however using a standard utility — if there is one — would be self-documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.  There is no standard utility on *nix systems for running a command and testing its exit code against a specific value.  Probably because it's trivial to write one yourself.

I'm guessing from the `%` in your code that you're using zsh.  If you're actually using csh (or tcsh), then things work differently.

That said, you can easily write a shell function to do this:

```
expect_status() {
  local expected=$1
  shift
  "$@"
  (( $? == expected ))
}
```

But that will run the command inside your current shell environment, which may have side effects you don't want.  It would probably be better realized as a script - just save it somewhere in your $PATH with the filename `expect_status` and give it read and execute permission:

```
#!/bin/bash
expected=$1
shift
"$@"
(( $? == expected ))
```

Or, eschewing bashisms:

```
#!/bin/sh
expected=$1
shift
${1+"$@"}
[ $? -eq $expected ]
```

Comment: I can do this, but this does not answer the question because I am asking of there is a standard utility doing this!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can check exit code of last command execution by referencing shell variable "$?".

```
$ ls -bogusOption          
ls: invalid option -- 'O'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
$ echo $?
2
```

shell can be used as utility to test exit code. say,

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "executing bogus option"
ls -bogusOption

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "command succeeded."
else
    echo "command failed"
fi

$ bash -xv ./test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "executing bogus option"
+ echo 'executing bogus option'
executing bogus option
ls -bogusOption
+ ls -bogusOption
ls: invalid option -- 'O'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "command succeeded."
else
    echo "command failed"
fi
+ '[' 2 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'command failed'
command failed
```

Comment: There is never any reason to do `command; if [ $? -eq 0 ]`.  Just do `if command; then echo "command succeeded"; else echo "command failed."; fi`.  Testing `$?` is *how `if` works*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a sense, there is a standard utility: the shell itself:

```
command1 && command2
```

The above will only execute `command2` if the exit code of `command1` is `0`. Alternatively, this:

```
command1 || command2
```

will only run `command2` if the exit code of `command1` was not 0.

To check for a specific exit status, you would use `$?` as described in the other answers:

```
command; [ "$?" -eq 64 ] && command2
```

So, the functionality you're looking for is essentially built directly into the shell and, therefore, you won't find a utility designed to do this.

Comment: Taking it a tiny step further, you could `alias` your command like this `alias check='[ "$?" -eq 64 ] && echo beep beep'`, then do `command; check`